# Forwarding function generic parameter to generic class type

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I have created enum with associated value and I want to be able to dynamically update associated value. As far as I know Swift doesn't support that at the moment.
Because of that I used following approach:

```
enum PersonInfo {

    class EnumValue<T> {
        var value: T
        init(_ value: T) {
            self.value = value
        }
    }

    // Instead of using String or Bool or any other type directly, use EnumValue wrapper
    case firstName(EnumValue<String>)
    case lastName(EnumValue<String>)
    case isAdult(EnumValue<Bool>)
}
```

I want to add function that would update `EnumValue.value` property in following way:

```
 func updateAssociatedValue<V>(_ updateValue: V) {
     let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
     for associatedValue in mirror.children {
         guard let value = associatedValue.value as? EnumValue<V> else {
             continue
         }
         value.value = updateValue
     }
 }
```

Problem is that this guard statement always fails (`guard let value = associatedValue.value as? EnumValue<V>`) and I can't figure it out why.

On the other hand, when I write `updateAssociatedValue` with typed type then things work properly:

```
// This works
func updateAssociatedValue(_ updateValue: String) {

  let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
  for associatedValue in mirror.children {
    guard let value = associatedValue.value as? EnumValue<String> else {
      continue
    }
    value.value = updateValue
  } 
}
```

Things compile normally but during the runtime guard statement always fails. Am I using generic value in some incorrect way? Should I use somehow `updateValue.`Type or `updateValue.self` (I tried but it didn't work).

Example of usage:

```swift
var array: [PersonInfo] = [
    .firstName(PersonInfo.EnumValue("John")),
    .lastName(PersonInfo.EnumValue("Doe")),
    .isAdult(PersonInfo.EnumValue(false))
]

print(array)
// John, Doe, false

array.first?.updateAssociatedValue("Mike")

print(array)
// Mike, Doe, false
```

I can always reassign enum value in array but if possible I want to avoid that. That's the reason for asking this question.

Comment: Please update your question with examples of how you use this function and what is it that you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to modify the associated value without reassigning the enum variable?

Comment: Just tried your generic function, and it works as expected